# How to get K max values from a histogram?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to extract let say the 3 max values in a matplotlib histogram.

There are a lot of ways to extract the (unique) max value in a histogram, but I don't find anything about extract the 2-3 or 4 max values in a histogram.

I also want it to be automatic (not specific to the following case).

Here is my data and my code:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import *    

Angle=[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.5526165117219184, 0.0, 1.559560844536934, 0.0, 1.5554129250143014, 1.5529410816553442, 1.5458015331759765, -0.036680787756651845, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -0.017855245139552514, -0.03224688243525392, 1.5422326689561365, 0.595918005516301, -0.06731387579270513, -0.011627382956383872, 1.5515679276951895, -0.06413211500143158, 0.0, -0.6123221322275954, 0.0, 0.0, 0.13863973713415806, 0.07677189126977804, -0.021735706841792667, 0.0, -0.6099169030770674, 1.546410917622178, 0.0, 0.0, -0.24111767845146836, 0.5961991412974801, 0.014704822377851432]

figure(1,figsize=(16,10))
plt.hist(Angle, bins=100,label='Angle')
show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`plt.hist` outputs the bin heights, the bin boundaries and the rectangular patches.
`np.argsort` can sort the values and use the result to index the other arrays.

The code below imports pyplot as `plt` because importing it as `*` can lead to al lot of confusion.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

Angle=[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.5526165117219184, 0.0, 1.559560844536934, 0.0, 1.5554129250143014, 1.5529410816553442, 1.5458015331759765, -0.036680787756651845, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -0.017855245139552514, -0.03224688243525392, 1.5422326689561365, 0.595918005516301, -0.06731387579270513, -0.011627382956383872, 1.5515679276951895, -0.06413211500143158, 0.0, -0.6123221322275954, 0.0, 0.0, 0.13863973713415806, 0.07677189126977804, -0.021735706841792667, 0.0, -0.6099169030770674, 1.546410917622178, 0.0, 0.0, -0.24111767845146836, 0.5961991412974801, 0.014704822377851432]
plt.figure(1,figsize=(10, 6))
values, bins, patches = plt.hist(Angle, bins=30)

order = np.argsort(values)[::-1]
print("4 highest bins:", values[order][:4])
print("  their ranges:", [ (bins[i], bins[i+1])   for i in order[:4]])

for i in order[:4]:
    patches[i].set_color('fuchsia')

plt.show()
```

Output:

```
4 highest bins: [21.  8.  3.  2.]
  their ranges: [(-0.03315333842372081, 0.03924276080176348), (1.4871647453114498, 1.559560844536934), (-0.1055494376492051, -0.03315333842372081), (0.5460154553801537, 0.6184115546056381)]
```

[image: resulting plot]

Another example highlighting the 3 highest bins:

```py
Angle = np.random.normal(np.tile(np.random.uniform(1, 100, 20 ), 100), 5 )
values, bins, patches = plt.hist(Angle, bins=100)
```

[image: second example]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this perfect answer!